# mod_rewrite does not rewrite, error.log shows no valuable information

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, webserver

This is the config of my apache2:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www
   <Directory />
      RailsBaseURI /
      PassengerResolveSymlinksinDocumentRoot on
      AllowOverride All
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteRule ^test.html$ test2.html
   </Directory>
   <Directory /var/www/redmine>
      RailsBaseURI /redmine
      PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
   </Directory>
```

When accessing test.html, it still opens test.html and not test2.html as it should.

This is what rewrite puts into the error.log when accessing test.html:

```
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test.html -> var/www/test.html
applying pattern '^test.html$' to uri 'var/www/test.html'
pass through /var/www/test.html
```

It doesn't say anything to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your real bug is using <Directory /> rather than a direcotry section for /var/www.  Your rewrite would match in that context and you wouldn't be opening up your entire filesystem.

When you use RewriteRule in Directory/Location/htaccess, the comparisons are relative to where you define them. That's what it's trying to guess at stripping.

If you simplify and move rewrite outside of Directory context algtogether, you'd need to add a leading slash to your comparison and substitution, along with the [PT] flag.

Comment: thats not what its trying to guess, because im not using .htaccess. Im just using the config file.
So ur proposing this?
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/test.html$ /test2.html [PT]

    <Directory />
               ...
           </Directory>

Comment: For rewriterule, <directory> and htaccess context are the same

Comment: maybe my english is just very bad...but i don't understand what i could actually do to have it go to test2.html when accessing test.html